# Получить координаты точки графика в Chart-e

Tags: delphi-7

Как щелчком мыши получить координаты точки графика, построенного в Chart-e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Щелчок мыши по графику видимо? Поймать событие `OnClickSeries`. `ValueIndex` дает номер точки в серии значений.

Answer (score 1):

В обработчик события `OnMouseDown` вставьте функцию:

```
void __fastcall Chart1::GetPoint(const int mX, const int mY, double& X, double& Y) const
{
    X = BottomAxis->CalcPosPoint(mX);
    Y = LeftAxis->CalcPosPoint(mY);
}
```